# Synonymous attribute names with XmlAttribute

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Our XML format has changed from

```
<foo bar="xyz" />
```

to

```
<foo abc="xyz" />
```

. Please notice the change of the attribute name from *bar* to *abc*.

Is it possible to support both attribute names with `XmlAttribute`?

I tried to tag the class member with `XmlAttribute` twice, but this results in a compile time error.

```
public sealed class Foo {
    [XmlAttribute("bar")] // Error: The attribute `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times
    [XmlAttribute("abc")]
    public string bar;
}
```

Any idea how to deal with synonym attribute names without writing a custom deserialization for the whole *Foo* class?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way with a getter, but this is not the best solution:

```
public sealed class Foo {
    // Both have to be public, otherwise they don't get deserialized
    [XmlAttribute("bar"), DefaultValue(null)]
    public string _bar;
    [XmlAttribute("abc"), DefaultValue(null)]
    public string _abc;

    public string bar {
        get {
            if (_bar != null) {
                return _bar;
            } else {
                return _abc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The disadvantage is, that both `_bar`and `_abc` are now part of *Foo*'s public API. Furthermore I can't declare that exactly one of both have to be present.